# 3D rotation matrix to quaternion

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry, matrix, rotation

There are multiple ways to represent a [3D rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions). The most intuitive way is the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) –
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}&A_{13}\\A_{21}&A_{22}&A_{23}\\A_{31}&A_{32}&A_{33}\end{bmatrix}$$
rotates a point \$p=(x,y,z)^T\$ by left-multiplication: \$p'=Ap\$. This is however inefficient since a 3D rotation has only three degrees of freedom, so I personally prefer the [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) representation where \$p\$ is interpreted as the quaternion \$0+xi+yj+zk\$ and then conjugated by the rotating unit quaternion \$q\$ to get \$p'=qpq^*\$. Dropping the scalar (first) part leaves the rotated 3D point.

\$A\$ can be converted to a quaternion \$q=s+ai+bj+ck\$ with the same effect as follows:
$$s=\frac{\sqrt{1+A_{11}+A_{22}+A_{33}}}2$$
$$a=\frac{A_{32}-A_{23}}{4s}\qquad b=\frac{A_{13}-A_{31}}{4s}\qquad c=\frac{A_{21}-A_{12}}{4s}$$
Note that \$-q\$ has the same effect as \$q\$ by distribution of scalars in \$qpq^*\$, so the quaternion representation is not unique.

### Task

Given a 3D rotation matrix – an orthogonal (to floating-point error) 3×3 real matrix with determinant 1 – output a quaternion with the same effect as that matrix to within \$10^{-6}\$ entrywise relative error.

You may use any reasonable and consistent formats for input and output, and any correct formula for the calculation (including the one in the previous section). In particular the code has to handle \$s=0\$ cases, for which alternate formulas are available from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701759):
$$a=\frac{\sqrt{1+A_{11}-A_{22}-A_{33}}}2\\
b=\frac{\sqrt{1-A_{11}+A_{22}-A_{33}}}2\\
c=\frac{\sqrt{1-A_{11}-A_{22}+A_{33}}}2$$
$$b=\frac{A_{32}+A_{23}}{4c}\qquad c=\frac{A_{13}+A_{31}}{4a}\qquad a=\frac{A_{21}+A_{12}}{4b}$$

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); fewest bytes wins.

### Test cases

These are in the format \$A\to q\$. The random cases were generated through [this program](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVJBTsMwEBRXX_jCqie7OKFpOSBEEO0PmmsUVW7jBEuJnTgOUvkJ4tIL_KnwGdZKQQFx4WR7ZnZnvPbLW7N3D0Yfjh-qbox1oPu62YPoQDfE6hJi3IRW6NzUYS4L0VdugzhlhOARBmZjjRNOGU11vGA3BJZYh6pQG1uLinbqScZUc80YEFhzSIa-ldKiKsPW0iUjsEJwDfeeyJUoKa6dKjU9nQ1qacIYKlUxqs6loysGtzBDY1ilswymMQQRAStdbzWsXntXBNfHZx-43Rn9KK3DTijvhhxdi0B0gTtnxU56F7iEOQGBPE3SOY-yIEkjPs88Qa-mHabYDuQM0cBrZmNyN5ARooHXRGPyFCztuOBbvsuGgO9n54WxOBulwV9a7iVdcMjdvpGx0o5x-AtNvTX2z_j35NA2iLxl6gNgvjEXfJE_9B4c6f1wWrzCaFwEGot-NAmdqVTnKDaYBHcTDi0jPvjGB8cPUUo69_X-kX__D_avtsNcDodh_QQ) – you can make your own cases there too!

```
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]] -> [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]] -> [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
[[0, -1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]] -> [0.7071067811865476, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7071067811865476]
[[-1, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 1]] -> [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]] -> [0.0, 0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865476, 0.0]
[[0.1508272311227814, -0.2824279103927633, -0.9473571775117411], [-0.7156381696218376, -0.692324273056756, 0.09246140338941596], [-0.6819920501971715, 0.6640192590336603, -0.3065375459878405]] -> [0.19491370659742277, 0.7330908965072773, -0.3403623223156108, -0.5556436573799196]
[[0.13019043201085, -0.4676759473774085, -0.874259492174647], [0.4976035235357375, 0.7934932016832866, -0.35037019314894013], [0.8575786755614011, -0.3894197569808834, 0.33602242201273236]] -> [0.7516159351202696, -0.01298853643440075, -0.5760382686201726, 0.32106805677246825]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does mean "Note that −q has the same effect as q"?

Comment: @EzioMercer \$qpq^*=(-q)p(-q)^*\$.

Comment: It's easy to golf that formula but it's hard to find a short way to handle the case \$s=0\$.

Comment: @alephalpha Alternative relations to avoid div-by-0 have been added.

Comment: The formulas for `a,b,c,d` must be like `a^2 = (...) / 4` because in this case `a` can be either negative or positive but if we write like `a = ( (...) ^ (1/2) ) / 2` then `a` can be only non negative number

Answer (score 7):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 83 bytes

```
m->qfjacobi(matconcat([2*trace(m),s=[(n=m-m~)[3,2],n[1,3],n[2,1]];s~,m+m~]))[2][,4]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVJLittAEIWcRMxKykim_tWN8VwiSyGCYuLgEHkcj2cxG18kG0MIOVNymlRbNgxhQHRXV733ql6hH7_342H78cv-_HNTrX49Hzdd-vNh6h6-b76O68dP23oaj-vH3Xo81j29Px7G9ed6atqnVV_vVlM3nZqeWxraXY8tl4taHIbl06md7qfT0DQ9DX0rwyz99939uN9_e6nHqnuo9oft7hjhXXncVZt6bJq26kOpgviW5cRbUOIhqtdwWf2Puha7mfG6eqN2r5PdW8pvcru5ukCFRE6MSOQJJSqwoERCnhE4kxvzJZnFWR3dFdElZo2coxontGyEid0uQMvEhc-g5ho5WEAmMRRgTllQs13YljBnAgXMoYtakGYST9IcWDOYWzOYsqtoTp4E9Do6BxKECRCSXoBiHi3LpO5ySyaX0JNMMbaJxwYWkj20lVjDUiiXzp5ZchGzxJRs9sIK7NGGUWJyQC7spK6eopEWT4gzsjjL4TcnSImlSIYFoFhFiMY6iG0YmvmfOZ_n-x8)

Using [this formula on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Quaternion):

> If the matrix contains significant error, such as accumulated numerical error, we may construct a symmetric \$4\times 4\$ matrix,
> $$\frac13 \begin{bmatrix}
>   Q_{xx}-Q_{yy}-Q_{zz}    &        Q_{yx}+Q_{xy}        &        Q_{zx}+Q_{xz}        &        Q_{zy}-Q_{yz}        \\
>          Q_{yx}+Q_{xy}    & Q_{yy}-Q_{xx}-Q_{zz}        &        Q_{zy}+Q_{yz}        &        Q_{xz}-Q_{zx}        \\
>          Q_{zx}+Q_{xz}    &        Q_{zy}+Q_{yz}        & Q_{zz}-Q_{xx}-Q_{yy}        &        Q_{yx}-Q_{xy}        \\
>          Q_{zy}-Q_{yz}    &        Q_{xz}-Q_{zx}        &        Q_{yx}-Q_{xy}        & Q_{xx}+Q_{yy}+Q_{zz}  
>  \end{bmatrix} ,$$
> and find the eigenvector, \$(x,y,z,w)\$, of its largest magnitude eigenvalue.

Comment: This is crying out for a terrible translation into Python :)

Comment: I tried the input matrix `[-7/9, 4/9, -4/9; 4/9, -1/9, 4/9; -4/9, 4/9, -1/9]` but the output is `[0, 0, 1/√2, 1/√2]` when I was expecting `[0, 1/3, 2/3, -2/3]`.

Comment: @Neil That isn't an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: @alephalpha I miscalculated my matrix; `[-7/9, 4/9, -4/9; 4/9, -1/9, -8/9; -4/9, -8/9, -1/9]` gives the output I expected. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7), 189 bytes

*Edit: Thanks to Neil for pointing out that the *Alternative Method* described [here](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/) was not reliable. Now using a port of the (hopefully safe) Java code on the same page.*

Expects a flat array of 9 values.

```javascript
a=>[0,s=1,2,3].map(i=>(j=m>>7+2*i&3)<3?(a[j^2||7]+a[7/j^6]*~-(m>>i+2&2))/s:s/4,m=a[0]+a[4]+a[8]>0?9607:a[4]>a[8]?a[0]>a[4]?3937:23122:28852,[0,1,2].map(i=>s+=a[i*4]*(m>>i&1||-1)),s=s**.5*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHbbptAEH3PV/AUAQY8t93ZdQt@6lcgIqE0bm0lcRSiPln9dXcW6lykBKERM3PmnDnDYfwzTrfP@6eX@vH48@68a89j2/VQTS1WVPHQPIxP@b7t8kP70HW6onJ/zcV33uZjf7ih00mH1djr@nDjh/JvnRtov6JrKor1tJnWUj20Yw8JIymEoYNt9KCbVOhSYZv6XUq3HFk3xEi0oRAcVbaIrfG6xLQysn0pQznrXOPpVGNR2LJTWTaupOL8rb/Ksr7HKgN7hyozigzfPlM2DNUMuqTW@QT/Bqov8x9R76nqj636a8Uvueo3VIMOAqldwk6hAcW60FAgIY0IHEk981yMouwUVR2iCs5mrKzoPAf00RMGVj9jfSROFAzOq7MaNBBJPAowhyjoov8/7wPGSOAAo5GjS1jvxVJy0dDew6LP4B2rExeDBgH3zgMbGoQJEIKbweLVhNPKqnIpBhXjlEi2vxedD9JIVFNwxM7cGX/S18gSE50PTMEvntgBqwkxijkA5GU@OHUaTMwld4gLNnmM5jwGCIElkZoVIDuK0dphiP3rH9V1rDJJobaYaJcE5xiWUi2XbOkMw9Vw1eyOzz/G29/5mLVddnt8nI73d8398Ve@y8dmdz@@5IU9538)

Comment: I don't think your linked formula works properly for `s=0` in particular I think `[[-7/9, 4/9, -4/9], [4/9, -1/9, 4/9], [-4/9, 4/9, -1/9]]` should result in at least one negative output.

Comment: @Neil Not sure it that changes anything, but it seems like your example matrix is not special orthogonal.

Comment: Yeah I miscalculated it should be `[[-7/9, 4/9, -4/9], [4/9, -1/9, -8/9], [-4/9, -8/9, -1/9]]`, and your answer still gets that wrong.

Comment: @Neil Thank you. Should be fixed now -- but not efficiently, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>77</s> 66 bytes

```
≔Ｅθ§ικη⟦Ｉ⊘₂⊕Ση⟧ＩＥθ×⊘₂⊕ΣＥη⎇⁼κμλ±λ∨±›⁰∨⁻§§θ⊖κ⊕κ§§θ⊕κ⊖κ∧κ∨§ι⁰∧⊖κ§ι¹¦¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDBbsMgDL3vKzgaiUrJuadqm7Ye2lXdbogDSqwGlZAVSLV9PTM07dpthyEkm8d79rObTvtm0DalRQhm52Cl3@Eg2CIuXYsfYATbcy5Yx@d3G29cBHmvQ4RnbY/Ywuth1B63wxBh6RqPPbqY4bGHjuejLroim6q/mR7DP2pkekd09E77T3gkpg2wF6wnS1awNe50RLD8dAR78TBhTx4peKgKuDJuDHAe6hzJyQN@dyyDXlsowB@iX5wfVbLKtdkntb7aZDV93NJvll1fRjll85SklDQE3VoJJmd1yaucUyxPpVSaHe0X) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅθ§ικη
```

Get the main diagonal of `A`.

```
⟦Ｉ⊘₂⊕Ση⟧
```

Calculate and output `s`.

```
ＩＥθ×⊘₂⊕ΣＥη⎇⁼κμλ±λ
```

Calculate and output `a`, `b` and `c`, but...

```
∨±›⁰...¹
```

change the sign if one of the following is negative:

```
∨⁻§§θ⊖κ⊕κ§§θ⊕κ⊖κ∧κ
```

`sa`, `sb` or `sc` respectively, or if `s` is zero then when calculating `b` or `c` then...

```
∨§ι⁰∧⊖κ
```

... `ab+sc` or `ac-sb` respectively, or if both `s` and `a` are zero when calculating `c` then...

```
§ι¹
```

... `bc+sa`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 283 bytes

```js
m=>((a='21',b='10',c='20',T=([a,b,c])=>S=1+C(0)*~-a+C(1)*~-b+C(2)*~-c,K=([a,b,s])=>m[a][b]+m[b][a]*~-s,C=a=>m[a][a])(2)<0?C(0)>C(1)?[K(a+0),T(c+0),K(b+1),K(0+a)]:[K(0+c),K(b+1),T(0+c),K(a+1)]:C(0)<-C(1)?[K(b+0),K(0+a),K(a+1),T('002')]:[T('222'),K(a),K(0+c),K(b+0)]).map(x=>x/2/S**.5)
```

Converted Code from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3183435) to JavaScript code (based on [this article](https://d3cw3dd2w32x2b.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/matrix-to-quat.pdf)):

> ```java
> if (m22 < 0) {
>    if (m00 >m11) {
>        t = 1 + m00 -m11 -m22;
>        q = Quaternion( t, m01+m10, m20+m02, m12-m21 );
>    }
>    else {
>        t = 1 -m00 + m11 -m22;
>        q = Quaternion( m01+m10, t, m12+m21, m20-m02 );
>    }
> }
> else {
>    if (m00 < -m11) {
>        t = 1 -m00 -m11 + m22;
>        q = Quaternion( m20+m02, m12+m21, t, m01-m10 );
>    }
>    else {
>        t = 1 + m00 + m11 + m22;
>        q = Quaternion( m12-m21, m20-m02, m01-m10, t );
>    }
> }
> q *= 0.5 / Sqrt(t);
> ```

Try it:

```js
f=m=>((a='21',b='10',c='20',T=([a,b,c])=>S=1+C(0)*~-a+C(1)*~-b+C(2)*~-c,K=([a,b,s])=>m[a][b]+m[b][a]*~-s,C=a=>m[a][a])(2)<0?C(0)>C(1)?[K(a+0),T(c+0),K(b+1),K(0+a)]:[K(0+c),K(b+1),T(0+c),K(a+1)]:C(0)<-C(1)?[K(b+0),K(0+a),K(a+1),T('002')]:[T('222'),K(a),K(0+c),K(b+0)]).map(x=>x/2/S**.5)

;[
  [
    [-7 / 9, 4 / 9, -4 / 9],
    [4 / 9, -1 / 9, -8 / 9],
    [-4 / 9, -8 / 9, -1 / 9],
  ],
  [
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
  ],
  [
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
  ],
  [
    [0, -1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
  ],
  [
    [-1, 0, 0],
    [0, -1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
  ],
  [
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, -1],
  ],
  [
    [0.1508272311227814, -0.2824279103927633, -0.9473571775117411],
    [-0.7156381696218376, -0.692324273056756, 0.09246140338941596],
    [-0.6819920501971715, 0.6640192590336603, -0.3065375459878405],
  ],
  [
    [0.13019043201085, -0.4676759473774085, -0.874259492174647],
    [0.4976035235357375, 0.7934932016832866, -0.35037019314894013],
    [0.8575786755614011, -0.3894197569808834, 0.33602242201273236],
  ],
].forEach(m => console.log(JSON.stringify(f(m))));
```

Thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) for the [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258001/3d-rotation-matrix-to-quaternion/258025?noredirect=1#comment570021_258025) to reduce bytes count

Comment: [Minor parameter optimization](https://tio.run/##dVDLbttADLz7K4ScJFdS@ViSu23lnvoVwh4UN3YTxFGRFEWSQ3/dpaQYToAEIKRZcnZmhzfD3@Fhe3/9@09zN/68Ou6646Hb9OW@K/vH@ql@rof6MlfdpsRPhx6y1/pf8@gYs5fjJ8eUvRw/V@t1K5/LQz/k/jJ/O/jH4feGvlBVlRdEBHBR1XuHAIQLhAm/QG86IR@/9qui6HusC/DKddH7H89wOuVcz6TT0Sfv8M@k5nT/Leu1VPN21Hzs@KFWc2a1KBDJiBGJLGLwKbQUKZAlBE5kyjw3UzAWQzNBtIBzGG8binJETUoY2XTmaiKeJBhETbwHLSQKigGYYwooSV/ua8SUCAQwuTjKxFUNfiRJzlaFxZ9BhU2CpGgxgLzKwM6GwAQIUWZyUHPj6clm4dSMFlwzJPL3a7B5IW1I5g5CLJ7O9Sd/SxzSJKeRKeqSiQXY3IgxeAJAXu5HMbHoZjKlQ1y4U8bkyVOEGDlMoh4FyJfisr4YYs15lVftbrz/MWx/lUPRbYrtePcw3l61t@O@3JVDVVXH/w)

Comment: `[[-7/9, 4/9, -4/9], [4/9, -1/9, -8/9], [-4/9, -8/9, -1/9]]` should give at least one negative value in the output.

Comment: @Neil Interesting testcase :) I just entered the given formulas... I will fix it ASAP (If I can)

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB/Octave, <del>539</del> 110 bytes

saved 429 bytes.

Thanks to all useful comments (@ceilingcat, @alephalpha, et al.).

---

the 110 bytes version proprosed by @ceilingcat is as follows:

```
function q=f(R)S=R-R';[V,L]=eig([2*trace(R),T=[S(3,2),S(1,3),S(2,1)];T',R+R']);[M,I]=max(diag(L));q=V(:,I);end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7BbsIwDAbg@55iN5ItrWI7dpJVfQAkdimIS9VDBQVV2mDd2LQ9PUtBSDDtEivx59/Zrw7tV3c8bj53q0O/390P5UZVel5WWTUp6qWZNWXXb1WND4f3dtWlnlmU9VyRQW3mCgyNBQ3oplhMTPVYTRpd1M9m2pSv7bda9@1WzbQuhnKpnsxUF91ufRwgranBWGMLa@B0ppom1/3H20v7owbQdwOO6tQpruy1wqTorLIx5sL@hFFibmTZBWT/LnXJ8TnuNi27YZyYjCwHtgE9EgCiD@BMlmNAhz6CpYheiNJTdJ7Yg/cM4B0UWe6BhQJIFIRAXhKSiDROkmXxLCa3EZ2As0QhOuAoaU4CxIiWLcSUB2xsLuLSDTkmKGLHfWSFybPjGHxwlq//Lvr4Cw)

one original explicit code (*maybe more fast?*) is

```
function q = rotm_to_quat(R)
    tr = trace(R);
    if tr > 0
        S = sqrt(tr + 1.0) * 2;
        qw = 0.25 * S;
        qx = (R(3,2) - R(2,3)) / S;
        qy = (R(1,3) - R(3,1)) / S;
        qz = (R(2,1) - R(1,2)) / S;
    elseif (R(1,1) > R(2,2)) && (R(1,1) > R(3,3))
        S = sqrt(1.0 + R(1,1) - R(2,2) - R(3,3)) * 2;
        qw = (R(3,2) - R(2,3)) / S;
        qx = 0.25 * S;
        qy = (R(1,2) + R(2,1)) / S;
        qz = (R(1,3) + R(3,1)) / S;
    elseif R(2,2) > R(3,3)
        S = sqrt(1.0 + R(2,2) - R(1,1) - R(3,3)) * 2;
        qw = (R(1,3) - R(3,1)) / S;
        qx = (R(1,2) + R(2,1)) / S;
        qy = 0.25 * S;
        qz = (R(2,3) + R(3,2)) / S;
    else
        S = sqrt(1.0 + R(3,3) - R(1,1) - R(2,2)) * 2;
        qw = (R(2,1) - R(1,2)) / S;
        qx = (R(1,3) + R(3,1)) / S;
        qy = (R(2,3) + R(3,2)) / S;
        qz = 0.25 * S;
    end
    q = [qw, qx, qy, qz];
end
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Matlab/Octave, but this seems to work (a port of my PARI/GP answer): [112 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc5BbsIwEAXQfU/RHXHrRJ4Zz9iulQMg0U1AbKIsIggoUgtNS6v29NQBIUHVjS3b7//xfnVov7rjcfO5Wx36/e5@KDdZpeZllVeTuCjreUYalZ5noGncUINqYr3Us6bs@m1W48PhvV11KaQXcTHR1WM1aVSsn/W0KV/b72zdt9tsplQcymX2pKcqdrv1cYA0qAZttIlGw2lNe0qu@4@3l/YnG0DdDTiq00u8stcKk6KzyseaC/tTRonZkeUXkP871CbH57rbtvyGcWIysgLYeHRIAIjOg9V5gR4tugCGAjohSlfBOmIHzjGAsxDzwgELeZAgCJ6cJCQBaUySYXEsujABrYA1RD5Y4CApJx5CQMMGQuoD1qYQsemEHBIUMeM8MsLk2HLwzlvD138XdfwF "Octave – Try It Online")